# Django REST Framework - Filter foreign key items for POST, PUT and PATCH

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple ModelSerializer :

```
class OfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ('id', 'accepted', 'comment', 'status', 'item_given', 'item_received')
```

With this model :

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    accepted = models.BooleanField()
    status = models.BooleanField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField("date published", default=timezone.now)

    item_given = models.ForeignKey("items.Item", related_name='item_given', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_received = models.ForeignKey("items.Item", related_name='item_received', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

And it is used by the following view :

```
class OfferViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Offer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OfferSerializer
```

The foreign key item_given is another model named Item which has a foreign key on user.

In the django rest framework's generated form I can select any Item for the item_given field when creating a new offer. But I'd like to be able to select only items where the foreign key user is equal to request.user.

I tried editing the def_queryset in the serializer but without success.
How can i achieve this?

I'm on an account who created no item but I get every items.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVfxo.png

Currently I'm logged with the user with id 3

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "asasd",
    description: "sdffsd",
    price_min: 123,
    price_max: 234,
    creation_date: "2016-11-15T17:35:11Z",
    archived: false,
    owner: 1,
    category: 1,
    image_set: [ ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "sdfsdffiss",
    description: "fsdfsd",
    price_min: 124,
    price_max: 1245,
    creation_date: "2016-11-15T19:39:02.225543Z",
    archived: false,
    owner: 1,
    category: 1,
    image_set: [ ]
},
{
    id: 8,
    name: "Test",
    description: "Test",
    price_min: 123,
    price_max: 234,
    creation_date: "2016-11-15T20:42:34.492041Z",
    archived: false,
    owner: 3,
    category: 1,
    image_set: [
        5
    ]
}
```

And when I go to create a new offer, every single items show up in the item_given field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean `get_queryset` and it's not a serializer method, it's a view set method. Thus, you'll have something like:

```
class OfferViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OfferSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Offer.objects.filter(item_given__owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I tried it, just wrote "item_given__owner" instead of "item_given__user" because the foreign key is named owner in the Item model but I still get every items in the list. I added an image showing the drop-down list.

Comment: The image you added is broken. Nevertheless, could you debug the returned offers to see if some of them really have a different user in `item_given.owner`? Because if it's really the case, my only guess is that you are hitting the wrong view or `get_queryset` isn't being executed because of some other odd reason.

Comment: I have added the output of items. What could prevent `get_queryset` from being executed?

Comment: I made some tests and apparently, the creation is prevented if I try to create an offer with an item related to someone else. But I still get a 201 Created and the list contains every items

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the form displaying every items but I could make it raise an error if the item is not owned by the user

```
def validate(self, data):
    if self.context['request'].user.userprofile != data['item_given'].owner:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Item given is not owned by the current user")
    return data
```